# Given a vector $u\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, determine which is the unit vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that maximizes the scalar product $\langle{u,x}\rangle$

Tags: calculus

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Given a fixed vector $u\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, determine which is the unit vector 
$x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that maximizes the scalar product $\langle{u,x}\rangle$

Comment: Could you show us a bit what you've tried so far? Also a vector in $u \in \mathbb R$ seems not quite right, could be a typo

Comment: $\dfrac{x}{\| x \|}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, one has:
$$|\langle u,x\rangle|\leqslant\|u\|\|x\|=\|u\|.$$
On the other hand:
$$\left\langle u,\frac{u}{\|u\|}\right\rangle=\|u\|.$$
Therefore, $u/\|u\|$ achieves the maximum.